# SQL Order by string, numbers appear last

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-order-by

I have a query that return a string column which I would like to sort by.
When I sort by ASC/DESC, I'm getting the same result.
Here is an output example:

```
AVI
ksky site
Secure East
Shlomi
VSEStaging
1200165
120186
120186
120186
120032
```

But I would to have the numbers before the alphabetic string.
For example for ASC:

```
1200165
120186
120186
120186
120032
AVI
ksky site
Secure East
Shlomi
VSEStaging
```

For example for DESC:

```
VSEStaging
Shlomi
Secure East
ksky site
AVI
120032
```

I currently use REGEX like so:

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR(UPPER(COLUMN_NAME), '^\D*') ,
TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_SUBSTR(UPPER(COLUMN_NAME), '\d+'))
```

Please assist.

Comment: Check out **[this link's last answer](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:9522557800346940016)**

Comment: The solutions provided are good for ASC but for DESC.

Comment: Is it one of the assumptions that every string will be either 100% digits (no other characters) or 100% letters (no other characters)? If that is not guaranteed, then you need to clarify: How should the string `123abcd` be ordered? How about `#!-` - where should that fall in the ordering? Etc.

Comment: @DavidFaiz did you try to simply add desc in the solution at the end of ORDER BY clause?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `regexp_like()`.  For the ascending sort:

```
order by (case when regexp_like(col, '^[0-9]+$') then 1 else 2 end) asc,
         col asc
```

Comment: @DavidFaiz - this will work for ASC and DESC, just change the last word from `asc` to `desc` (don't touch the first line of code, only the second). This assumes that your strings are (1) 100% digits and (2) everything else. See my Comment/Question under your original post (for clarification).

Comment: @DavidFaiz - did you try just changing both `asc` to `desc`?

Comment: @AlexPoole - I take it the OP wants "numbers" at the top regardless of ASC or DESC - so he should only change the second ASC to DESC.

Comment: @mathguy - that isn't what's shown at the end of the question. That has strings first (desc; possibly case-insensitive to add to the fun) followed by numbers (only one shown, not sure if they should then be asc or desc, the later sees a reasonable assumption).

Answer (score 0):

You could try something different like this:

```
order by translate(upper(col), '1234567890', 'abcdefghij')
```