# PostgreSQL order by, numbers last

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by

name2 could be string or number. I.e. `'one two'` or `12`

I would like to order names so that numbers to be last, i.e:

```
a a
b b
one two
1
22
```

```
select name1, name2 
from names 
order by name2
```

Q: how one would do it?

P.S. in oracle it is like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42346191/sql-order-by-string-numbers-appear-last).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a boolean expression in `order by`, e.g.:

```
select name1, name2 
from names 
order by left(name2, 1) <= '9', name2
```

[Db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=62c32b9e2092237b2ae49eacba925c19)

Comment: would it work with aliases? like  `select name1, name2, name2 as name-alias from order by left (name-alias, 1) <= '9', name-alias)` (in my case the name-alias got some transformation applied based on name2). and now it fails with  '"name-alias" does not exist'

Comment: You **can** use an alias for a column but **not** in an expression, e.g. `order by left(name2, 1) <= '9', name_alias`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `REGEXP_REPLACE()` function with `'[^[:digit:]]*'` posix, to determine whether the string has a digit or not in it, including an asterisk at the end to anchor a regular expression to the end of the source text :

```
SELECT name2
  FROM t
 ORDER BY REGEXP_REPLACE(name2,'[^[:digit:]]*',''), name2
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=336899a95e3e1291c69634176bd26ce3)</kbd>

Comment: it gives me bunch of duplicated values as result - one value duplicated over and over like "aa", "aaa", etc.. (not sure why if it works on your demo).